# Back up (save) the same file at periodic intervals

Tags: ubuntu, backup, file-management, cron

I am saving a stream in my HDD.
I'd like to copy the file periodically into a subfolder `backup` such that the older versions of the the file are not deleted.

Simply put

1. Assume the original file is `somefolder/data`.
2. The first backup should be `somefolder/backup/data.1`
3. The second backup should be `somefolder/backup/data.2`
4. This process should continue in an interval of t minutes/seconds

How do I go about doing this? I use Ubuntu 13.10 64b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want backup with different names, you can use date time (with seconds) instead a number.

```
# mkdir somefolder
# touch somefolder/data
# date
Tue May  6 05:40:32 WIB 2014
# cp somefolder/data somefolder/data.$(date "+%s")
# ls somefolder/
data  
data.1399329674
# date
Tue May  6 05:41:24 WIB 2014
# cp somefolder/data somefolder/data.$(date "+%s")
# ls somefolder/
data 
data.1399329674
data.1399329686
```

To automate the backup, you can use one-line-command like this

```
while true; do cp somefolder/data somefolder/backup/data.$(date "+%s"); sleep 3; done
```

The phrase `sleep 3` means the script should wait 3 seconds before backup again.

Comment: `while : ; do cp -vt ./backup/ --backup=numbered -- data; sleep 5; done` does the numbering in integral values